# .htaccess and subdirectory control

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, .htaccess

If I add a master .htaccess to the root directory, what aspects get carried down to the sub-directories? Like do the settings in .htaccess carry down to `/root/sub1/` and `/root/sub2/.`

I am wanting to block robots, spam, bots, and other vectors with my .htaccess and would like to know what would carry down. This is for a Joolma and Drupal type based websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

htaccess carries down to all sub-directories. Unless there's another htaccess file under that directory, it'll get overridden.

Meaning that unless you explicitly override htaccess protocol in the children of a directory - the parent will cast it's rules downward the tree. You can override these directives via adding additional htaccess directives in any children directories harbored by the aforementioned, parental directory.

edit: get out of my brain lol

Answer (score 0):

htaccess carries down to all sub-directories. Unless there's another htaccess file under that directory, it'll get overridden.

Meaning that unless you explicitly override htaccess protocol in the children of a directory - the parent will cast it's rules downward the tree. You can override these directives via adding additional htaccess directives in any children directories harbored by the aforementioned, parental directory.